# "Cousined to them" expression

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

What is the expression that sounds like "cousined to them" meaning accepted or gotten used to?

For example,

> The city councilors passed the building code but the planning
>   department was set in its way and it was some time before they
>   cousined to the new regulations.

I can't remember the exact spelling.

Comment: I think you mean "accustomed"? "...it was some time before they became accustomed to the new...". Or "adjusted": "...it was some time before they adjusted to the new..."

Comment: @MarvMills No I do not mean accustomed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because apparently the OP [made up that sentence to illustrate the usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/78223/emma-dash). Without an *actual* context involving a [competent] native speaker, there are simply too many possibilities (since we don't know for sure the *exact* context above is in fact "credible" for the target word/phrase).

Comment: Acclimated?   before they acclimated to the new

Comment: With some tweaks you could also fit "consigned" in there as well.

Comment: I can't quote the email I used it in because is a work email and it contains sensitive matters. The example sentence I wrote is exactly analogous to the desired usage.

Comment: -1, After looking at your answer, it's clear that this question was intended to ask how to spell a phrase that you've used, which is not an entirely unreasonable question. However, this question appears to be asking for an appropriate phrase that sounds like another phrase, which is a completely different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some additional research I found that the spelling I have is actually the correct spelling. For example:

> The President, after hearing Heap, said he had rather **cousined up to**
>   Banks, but for some time past had begun to think he was erring in so
>   doing.
>   -- Diary of Gideon Wells (1911)

and

> The Pleasures of the Imagination are not wholly **cousined to** such
>   particular Authors as are conversant in material Objects, but are
>   often to be met with among the Polite Masters of Morality, Criticism,
>   and Other Speculations abstracted from Matter, who, tho' they do not
>   directly treat of the visible Parts of Nature, often draw from them
>   their Similitudes, Metaphors, and Allegories. -- The Spectator No. 421
>   (1755)

and

> I was happy. I was who I wanted to be. Not the feckless *myself* I'd
>   been tied to at home and still **cousined** to two and a half hours
>   west in Toronto but something better, infinitely, a character I'd com
>   to love, to chase, somebody with a myth and a story. 
> --"On earth as it
>   is" by Steven Heighton (1995)

Comment: In your first example, I think there's a good chance that the diary entry was a misspelling of ["cozied up to"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cozy+up+to) and in your second example, it seems to mean "associated with/related to.'

Comment: OED says the verb ***to cousin** = To call cousin, claim kinship with* is ***obsolete, rare***. The Diary of Gideon Wells may have been published in 1911, but it was written at least half a century before (and was probably "archaic" in style, even then). Therefore I doubt your "made up example" usage could conceivably have occurred, since it probably long predates "city planning departments".

Comment: @PapaPoule I have attached an image of the printed text.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am just trying to ascertain the correct spelling here, not characterize periods when the expression was used.

Comment: @Emma Dash: I'm having *real* trouble squaring this question with [*only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face*](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) (from the ELU FAQ). How on earth can you be in the position of needing an *expression that sounds like* somthing, when the word you apparently seek was only ever ***rare***, and probably hasn't been used at all since sound recording/transmission became technically possible?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that YOU had misspelled it, but that the diarist Wells had done so originally (or later during its transcription). [Of the 10 or so hits for this quote](https://www.google.com/search?q=%27cousined+up+to+Banks%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22cousined+up+to+Banks%22) , 2 of them have "cousined" in quotation marks, indicating perhaps that "cousined" wasn't the right word (or right spelling of the word), which was all that I was trying to say. @EmmaDash

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually I already used the word in an email, and I wanted to make sure I spelled it correctly, so if I use it again I don't make the same mistake.

Comment: If the meaning is "to relate to as if a relative", or something along those lines, there's no reason to believe the spelling would be anything other than "cousined".

Comment: @Emma: Regardless of how you spelled it, it's probably fair to say you "made a mistake" in using *any* verb derivative of ***cousin***, or misspelling of ***cosy up*** (US ***cozy up***) in an email.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Both Mia Anderson and Kevin Young, leading contemporary poets, have used the word "cousined", but I guess they are making a mistake according to you.

Comment: @Emma: There's a world of difference between "valid, credible" creative use of language in *poetry*, and normal English (such as one might use in emails, or discuss on ELL). But if you'd posted links to either of those poets' usages in your original question text it would have made it a lot easier to assess the proper response.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Added a quote from Steven Heighton's 1995 short story "On earth as it is". How many more citations do you want and in what categories? Another 20 citations in non-fiction, technical writing, business self-help books, and fantasy science fiction? What's going to make you happy? All I asked for is how to SPELL the word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers although city planning goes back to Gilgamesh,  'city planning departments' named as such caught on after Haussmann in mid 19th century Paris http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges-Eug%C3%A8ne_Haussmann

Comment: None of the quotes as posted appear to use "cousined" to mean "accepted or gotten used to".  Regardless, it isn't an appropriate choice for business communication, IMO.

Comment: @Emma: I don't have a problem with you "verbing" ***cousin*** any more than I mind treating ***verb*** the same way. I'd guess many if not *most* of the (relatively few) total usages of your past tense form that ever occur are probably effectively "ad-hoc coinages" (you wouldn't find it in many dictionaries). I'm still baffled as to what you're asking for here. If you *knew* you wanted this quirky usage, surely the spelling couldn't be otherwise? But did you imagine it was "standard English"? And are you now trying to convince me it's *standard English*, and should be in more dictionaries?

Answer (score 7):

"Cotton to" means "to take a liking to someone or something" ([The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cotton+to)).

> The city councilors passed the building code but the planning department was set in its way and it was some time before they cottoned to the new regulations.

Comment: It may have been this, I seem to remember "cousined", though.

Comment: I have never heard "...cotton to...", though "cottoned on to..." is fairly common to mean "realised".

Comment: @MarvMills The Free Dictionary defines "cotton to something" as "to take a liking to something" and "cotton _on_ to something" as "to take a liking to something _quickly_" **or** "to come to understand something." However, I wouldn't be surprised if the two are used interchangeably, especially since they're regional slang words.

Comment: I can attest that "Cotton to" in the sense quoted from the Free Dictionary is regional AmE, chiefly associated now with the South, I'd guess, but I've also heard it used by older people in the rural West.

Comment: "Cotton to" is familiar to Americans of a certain age because it was a favorite expression of Fess Parker when he portrayed Daniel Boone on television in the late 60s (a show that boys, at least, never missed).  I'm thinking it was also used on "The Beverly Hillbillies" in roughly the same era, but I'm not sure I ever heard it much "in real life" (even though I lived in a "border state"), and it's hard to say if it was really a common expression at one time or just a Hollywoodism.

Answer (score 3):

The word might be *cozened*, but it has a slightly different definition than you want.

[Merriam-Webster definition:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cozen)

> to deceive, win over, or induce to do something by artful coaxing and wheedling or shrewd trickery.

I pronounce it exactly like *cousin* only with an /ə/ except an /ɪ/ in the second syllable. And since these are unstressed syllables, many native English speakers will pronounce them exactly the same.

Possibly you've mixed up the pronunciation of *cozened* with the definition of *cottoned to*.

Comment: Yes, I know the word cozened, but that is a little different. You cozen somebody, but that is different than "cozening up to", I think.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there might not be mistranscription (#3) as well as a mishearing involved here...

> 1: *...it was some time before they **consented** to the new regulations.*
>    2: *...it was some time before they **cosied up** to the new regulations.*
>    3: *...it was some time before they **co-signed** <strike>to</strike> the new regulations.*

Comment: I made up that sentence to illustrate the usage.